# i can't clear all null rows in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

here is my code:

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim() == "")
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
        }
    }
```

also tried:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim() == "")
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.Rows[i]);
        }
    }
```

[image]

and i expect to see only the row with 'item001'
i can't achieve this result i get some rows with null value:
[image]
and it gets worse with more than item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're removing items from collection as you're enumerating, which will result in undefined behavior. You may need a copy of it.

```
var rows = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().ToArray();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in rows)
{
    if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim() == "")
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
    }
}
```

Or with for loop

```
for (int i = dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i >=0; i--)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim() == "")
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.Rows[i]);
    }
}
```

It fails to work properly since you remove elements from collection as iterating it; removing would cause the collection to re-adjust its indices isn't it? So when you go to next iteration by calling `MoveNext` you get unexpected element.

Comment: Or a `for`-loop from `Count - 1` to `0`.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Yes, There are number of options available that's why I framed a sentence as `You may`

Comment: i did use for and it also leave some unwanted result

Comment: but... You should use a `reverse for` as @C.Evenhuis said. `for(int i = dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i>=0; i--)`

Comment: that is confusing, see my in my question i updated with `for` loop, is it what you meant?

Comment: Since in C# collections are zero based, meaning that if the condition of for loop is `i = dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1` then the last item won't be checked.

Comment: @chridam No, It will check. As you said collection is zero based for index but not for `Count`. Count starts from `1`. When count `1` there is only one element which you can access through zero based index. makes sense?

Comment: Gotcha, got a bit confused on the reverse for-loop but cheers for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than comparing against `""`, try `string.IsNullOrEmpty` method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
   {
      dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.Rows[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: it says that there is expecting ")"

Comment: My bad, added the missing bracket and braces (optional for one liners) in the updated answer.

Comment: This won't compile as `string.IsNullOrEmpty` can only work with `string` where as `Value` property is `Object`; even if it would have get compiled this also wont work.

Comment: well it leaves some unwanted result too!